# Path for persistent, managed hive tables in Spark 1.4

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am new to Spark and working on JavaSqlNetworkWordCount example to append the word count in a persistent table. I understand that I can only do it via HiveContext. HiveContext, however, keeps trying to save the table in /user/hive/warehouse/. I have tried changing the path by adding

```
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/home/user_name");
```

and by adding the property

```
 <property><name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
 <value>/home/user_name</value></property>
```

$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml, but nothing seems to work. If anyone else has faced this problem, please let me know if/how you resolved it. I am using Spark1.4 on my local RHEL5 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. It looks like spark-submit was creating a metastore_db directory in root directory of the jar file. If metastore_db exists, then hive-stie.xml values are ignored. As soon as I removed that directory, code picked up values from hive-site.xml. I still cannot set the value of the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property from the code, though.